# Export в Excel, формат строки

Tags: delphi, excel

Если при выводе в Excel задать такую строку

```
ExcelServer.AutomationServer.Cells[k, col+1] := '01/01'
```

То в Excelе она переводится в дату.

Как сделать, чтобы этого не происходило?

Comment: Перед этим присвоением задать формат ячейки -- текстовый. Как там это будет по-excel'вски -- не помню, посмотрите help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кавычку перед значением поставить попробуйте:

```
ExcelServer.AutomationServer.Cells[k, col+1] := '''01/01'
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление надо было 4 кавычки впереди поставить ))

Answer (score 1):

Вариант: перед вставкой задать формат ячеек *Текстовый*.

Comment: Слишком просто ))
Пробовал все равно меняется. 
А правильное решение уже есть.

Comment: Чем проще, тем проще :)
А правильных решений может быть не одно.